# Couldn't match expected type Int with actual type Int -> Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The following code produces an error:

```
power:: Int -> Int -> Int
power a b 
        | a ==0 || b == 0      = 0
        | otherwise   = power ((multiply a a) (b-1))

multiply:: Int -> Int -> Int
multiply a b
        | a <= 0        = 0
        | otherwise     = (multiply (a-1) (b)) + b
```

The returned error is

```
power.hs:6:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Int -> Int'
    In the return type of a call of `power'
    Probable cause: `power' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: power (multiply (a a) b - 1)
    In an equation for `power':
        power a b
          | b == 0 = 0
          | otherwise = power (multiply (a a) b - 1)
```

Comment: That error doesn't match that code. That's impolite!

Comment: If you're representing mathematical taking powers and multiplying, you'll need to change your definitions. At the moment, power 2 0 == 0, whereas 2^0=1. In fact because of this, power will only ever be 0. For other numbers, power squares every time, so that once you've fixed the 0 issue, you'd get power x y calulating x^(2^y). You'd need to keep track of the starting number y to stop this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the expression `power ((multiply a a) (b-1))`. The problem is that extra pair of parentheses. You're actually only passing one argument to `power`, which is `((multiply a a) (b-1))`. This expression is itself invalid, because the result of `(multiply a a)` is `Int`, which cannot accept arguments.

You should rewrite this as

```
| otherwise   = power (multiply a a) (b-1)
```

Comment: Thank you - I tried compiling again with simply:  "power (multiply(a a) (b-1)"   as well as     "power multiply a a b-1"   and "power multiply a a (b-1)"    and with all parentheses possibility listed, it is still parsing the arguments to power as one integer only.  Why would this be?

Comment: @user1690181: None of those matches the expression I gave you. Are you just adding and deleting syntax willy-nilly and hoping it works? Just use what I already typed.